# Find all emails with event invitations that are in the past in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I get a lot of event invites. Often, I can get to these emails only later. Thus, I want a way to find and mass delete all emails with invitations to events that were in the past. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Event invites from where? Google Calendar? Facebook? `*.ics` files? Something else? (Please [edit] your question.) I'm sure a search can find the messages you're looking for, but it's going to depend quite a bit on the source.

Comment: A lot of them are in plaintext email. Not integrated with other services.

Answer (score 3):

you can simply search with this string : `filename:ics` you'll find all the invitations.

After that you can select all of them and delete them.

You can mix operators to do something more precise like : `filename:ics after:2010/8/20 before:2016/8/01`